# Can't understand recursion in function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I can't understand how it works. Why the output has the first line, where var X == 1 ?
And, how compiler doesn't give an error if new_var is not defined anywhere as a integer ?
Is it because of call stack works like that ? It returns from the last call, so after returning 1, new_val becomes == 1 ?!

Output:  
I'm here!!!!  X is: 1  
I'm here!!!!  X is: 2, and new_var is 1
I'm here!!!!  X is: 3, and new_var is 2
I'm here!!!!  X is: 4, and new_var is 6
24

```
def fact_rec(x):
    if x > 0:         
        if x == 1:
            print(f"I'm here!!!!  X is: {x}")
            return 1
        else:            
            new_var = fact_rec(x-1)
            print(f"I'm here!!!!  X is: {x}, and new_var is {new_var}")
            return new_var*x
    else:
        return "It's negative"
print(fact_rec(4))
```

Comment: just a side note, what if the user inputs zero?

Comment: zero is not negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for, fact_rec(4) The function will check if 4 is greater than zero or not, it is here. Then it will check if it is equal to 1 or not, it is not here. So, it will call fact_rec(3) and same thing will be repeated.

When x == 1, `print(f"I'm here!!!!  X is: {x}")` will be triggered and the function will return 1 to the calling function i.e fact_rec(2) and so on.
Hence, first of all condition for x = 1 will be printed followed by x = 2 and so on.

Please refer the image below:

[image: Function Calls]